# Try every line without exception prematurely breaking code

Tags: python-3.x, try-except

I would like to write a single try-except statement that is able to run multiple try statements without the code breaking.

`s = "hello, this is a string."`

Using the above string as an example:

```
ls = []
try:
    ls.append(s.split())
    ls.append(s.str.split()) # expected error
    ls.append(s.split(","))
    ls.append(s.split("i"))
except:
    pass
```

Above is what I tried originally but the code stops by the second try-statement.

```
ls = []
try:
    ls.append(s.split())
except:
    pass
try:
    ls.append(s.str.split()) # expected error
except:
    pass
try:
    ls.append(s.split(","))
except:
    pass
try:
    ls.append(s.split("i"))
except:
    pass
```

Eventually, I was able to get all my strings appended to the list with the above code. Is there a better way of doing this than writing individual try-except statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [fuckit](https://pypi.org/project/fuckit/) module.
Wrap your code in a function with `@fuckit` decorator:

```
import fuckit

@fuckit
def func():
    code a
    code b #if b fails, it should ignore, and go to c.
    code c #if c fails, go to d
    code d
```

Or you can try this :

```
def a():
    try: # a code
    except: pass # or raise
    else: return True

def b():
    try: # b code
    except: pass # or raise
    else: return True

def c():
    try: # c code
    except: pass # or raise
    else: return True

def d():
    try: # d code
    except: pass # or raise
    else: return True

def main():   
    try:
        a() and b() or c() or d()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Interesting module, thanks! Though I suppose it's not good practice to not raise exception

Comment: Yes, it's better to raise the exception. You can raise the exceptions as it fits your code. I just kept a generalized code so as to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, when an error occurs in a try statement, it will immediately go to the except statement which is why your code doesn't execute after the second try statement.

Though there are probably better solutions to your question, here is my attempt for your problem:

```
ls = []
char=[' ',',','i']

for i in char:    
    try:
        ls.append(s.split(i))
        ls.append(s.str.split(i))
    except:
        pass
print(ls)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the split method was just an example. What I really wanted to know was if there is a way to run all try statements without breaking even while raising an exception. I'm actually building a dictionary with multiple keys from a JSON, and certain keys can only be found in one JSON and not the other, so I can't rely on reordering my try statements as you have done. For now, I shall just proceed with my ugly multiple try-except statements